# Can anyone explain when two imports of the same Python module can result in two different module objects?

Tags: python, python-import

Last year, I wrote the following three modules in Python 3.7.2:

```py
# my_module.py
my_counter = 0                                                                                                                                                                                               

def increment_counter():                                                                                                                                                                                     
  global my_counter                                                                                                                                                                                          
  my_counter += 1
```

```py
# client_module1.py                                                                                                                                                                                          

import my_module                                                                                                                                                                                             

def increment_counter():                                                                                                                                                                                     
  my_module.increment_counter()                                                                                                                                                                              
  print('Counter from client 1 is: %d' % my_module.my_counter
```

```py
# client_module2.py                                                                                                                                                                                          

import my_module                                                                                                                                                                                             

def increment_counter():                                                                                                                                                                                     
  my_module.increment_counter()                                                                                                                                                                              
  print('Counter from client 2 is: %d' % my_module.my_counter
```

Then, I tried the following in IPython:

```py
     In [1]: import client_module1                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     In [2]: import client_module2                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     In [3]: client_module1.increment_counter()                                                                                                                                                                   
     Counter from client 1 is 1                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     In [4]: client_module2.increment_counter()                                                                                                                                                                   
     Counter from client 2 is 1                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     In [5]: client_module1.my_module is client_module2.my_module                                                                                                                                                 
     Out [5]: False
```

I assumed that this is just the unfortunate way that Python works.

Today, after reading documentation that claims that the above result isn't what happens, I tried the experiment again. But I got different results:

```py
     In [1]: import client_module1                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     In [2]: import client_module2                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     In [3]: client_module1.increment_counter()                                                                                                                                                                   
     Counter from client 1 is 1                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     In [4]: client_module2.increment_counter()                                                                                                                                                                   
     Counter from client 2 is 2                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     In [5]: client_module1.my_module is client_module2.my_module                                                                                                                                                 
     Out [5]: True
```

Apparently, this second result is how Python modules are supposed to behave. Documentation claims that the only exceptions occur when the same module is imported via different explicit paths (such as directly via PYTHONPATH, and then indirectly through a containing directory that is also on PYTHONPATH), or by different methods (such as `import my_module` in one place but `from somewhere import my_module` someplace else).

But that's not what happened here. The files were all in the current working directory when I started IPython during both experiments, and the import statements were exactly the ones shown above. PYTHONPATH was unset, and there were no extra files in the directory.

Does anyone know which Python import edge case can cause this to happen sometimes but not others? It's very important to know in order to be able to do certain things involving global state reliably.

In both experiments, I used Python 3.7.2 and IPython 7.33.0.

Comment: All we can tell you is that you have forgotten (or never noticed) some important details of your earlier situation. Maybe you screwed with `sys.path` or `sys.modules`. Maybe you had a typo. We can't tell you what happened last year based only on a fuzzy memory of behavior you cannot reproduce.

Comment: I carefully documented the behavior and the steps I took to get it. There's no code listed here that screws with `sys.path` or `sys.modules`, therefore I didn't mess with `sys.path` or `sys.modules`.